# What is the timeout of a query in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server

I was running a query to delete in batches of a huge table. After say around 3 hrs sometimes 4 hrs I get a message saying

> Invalid object name '#table_name#'

After sometime is there a connection lost or something? What is the cause here?

Comment: Sounds more like a flaky connection to me or perhaps your spid being killed by some one/thing. SQL Server doesn't timeout queries and client libraries that do typically default to 30 seconds if you don't set them differently. How are you connecting? What application are you using to run these batches?

Comment: I am running directly in sql server 2008 query window

Comment: And what does your code look like? Are you running multiple batches with (say) `GO 1000` or is it one batch in a `WHILE` loop?

Comment: `set rowcount 10000
while 1 = 1
begin 
delete from grid_info where /...some logic..../
if @@rowcount = 0
   break
end
set rowcount 0`

Comment: Well that's all one batch so if your connection was being dropped the batch itself would stop. You wouldn't just get an error about a missing temp table. Is the temp table a `#local` or `##global` one? Can you add the exact code to your question?

Answer (score 2):

To answer the specific question: by default there is no timeout while running a query against the database engine. It will happily wait or days for an operation to complete whether the delay is due to the actual statement taking a long time to process or due it being sat waiting for other connections to release relevant locks.

Standard connection libraries like ADO implement timeouts, after which they will tell SQL Server to cancel the current operation and drop the connection.

There *are* timeout settings governing various processes (login processes, or situations where the database engine itself is asking a remote resource to perform some action, and such) but these do not affect queries given direct to the database engine.

For more specific help you'll need to add further details (the code of your query, the exact error message, perhaps some notes on your structure (is "#tablename# the name of an actual table in your DB?) so we can see if there is something there that would cause the error you have seen.